# hashtable search in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hash-map

I've implemented the search/insert part of a hashtable in JavaScript.
This is in linear probing style. It resizes when the array is out of space.

```js
var share = { bucketSize: 10 };

function hash(key){
  return key % share.bucketSize;
}

function expandArr(arr){
  share.bucketSize = share.bucketSize * 2;
  let newArr = [];
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    let item = arr[i];
    let key = item.key;
    hashInsert(key, item, newArr);
  }
  arr = newArr;
}

function hashInsert(key, data, arr){
  let bucketKey = hash(key);
  let hasReset = false;
  let pointer = bucketKey;
  while(true){
    if(pointer >= share.bucketSize){ // bound check
      pointer = 0;
      hasReset = true;
    }
    if(pointer === bucketKey && hasReset){ // all full
      expandArr(arr);
      bucketKey = hash(key);
      pointer = bucketKey;
      hasReset = false;
    }
    if(arr[pointer] === undefined){ // found space
      arr[pointer] = { key: key, data: data };
      break;
    }
    pointer++;
  }
}
function hashSearch(key, arr){
  let bucketKey = hash(key);
  let hasReset = false;
  let pointer = bucketKey;
  while(true){
    if(pointer === bucketKey && hasReset){ // complete cycle
      return undefined;
    }
    if(pointer >= share.bucketSize){ // bound check
      pointer = 0;
      hasReset = true;
    }
    let curr = arr[pointer];
    if(curr === undefined){ // not found
      return undefined;
    }
    if(curr.key === key){ // found it
      return curr;
    }
    pointer++;
  }
}

var arr = [];

for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
  hashInsert(i, 'data ' + i, arr);
  console.log( hashSearch(i, arr) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks good. I'm not sure what feedback you are looking for, but here's a little:

- use `const` where you can, instead of `let`
- the naming is a little confusing at times, hash vs. key. Maybe if you call the `hash` function `calcHash` then you can call the value it returns a `hash` and not have to call it a `bucketKey`... or maybe the function should be `calcBucketKey`.
- it seems like the scoping of `arr` may be off... especially in `expandArr`. I believe the argument is going to override the global definition, so I don't think that the last line that re-assigns `arr` is going to change the global, but rather a local variable going out of scope.
- consider using the modulo operator to loop around the array. It can save some checks against the array size.

Comment: Your point 3 is correct. `arr` is an argument of the function `expandArr` and thus is scoped to that function. The last line of that function `arr = newArr;` is redundant. Point 4, referring to  `%`. It is called the "remainder operator"  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_() not (modulo or sometimes modulus) operator. The behaviours are distinct in that `-3 % 4 === -3` while  `-3 mod 4 == 1` (Note `mod` is not a JS operator) It is unfortunate that `%` has been called modulo in many languages.